# PHP Extracting a part of the string if found

Tags: php, laravel

I am scraping a website and finding a string, then when that string is found, i will be extracting a part of that string.

I am looking for a string "twitter:image" in a website, then when found, i will be extracting the "content" value of that. So here's an example of the website that i'm scraping. This is the HTML or "View Source" of that website:

[image]

Here is an example of my code:
I am using a library called "ProxyCrawl"

```
$ch = new ProxyCrawl();

$response = $ch->get($link, false);

if ($response->original_status == 200) {
    $result = $response->body;
     if (strpos($result, 'name="twitter:image"') !== false) {
        Log::debug("found!");
        //then extract the content
     } else {
        //do nothing              
     }

 }
```

I already have the code on checking whether the "twitter:image" exist, but i don't have the code when extracting the "content" value.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is your page you try to search through always the same DOM? In this case you can try XPATH expressions in order to determine the existence of this element and easy extract the string.

Comment: @LucaJung - how can i use that? do you have an example, please?

Comment: Is your meta coming inside the body tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `<meta name="twitter:image" />` is a unique element on page then use this:

```
$ch = new ProxyCrawl();
$response = $ch->get($link, false);

if ($response->original_status == 200) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($response->body);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

    $element = $xpath->query("//meta[@name='twitter:image']/@content");

    if (!empty($element->item(0))) {
        $imageUrl = $element->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if there are multiple elements of this kind, you will need to iterate:

```
$ch = new ProxyCrawl();
$response = $ch->get($link, false);

if ($response->original_status == 200) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($response->body);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

    $imageUrls = [];
    $elements = $xpath->query("//meta[@name='twitter:image']");

    if ($elements !== false) {
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $imageUrls[] = $element->getAttribute('content');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really quick example but a regex would be the way to go:

`/(name=\"twitter:image\")(.)content=\"(.+)\"/im`

This would match a string that contains `name="twitter:image"` followed by `content="`. You can get the text of content from the third grouping:

```
$str = '<meta data-rl="true" name="twitter:image" content="testing"';
$regex = '/(name="twitter:image")(.)content="(.+)"/im';
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $results);
print_r($results);
```

- This is a rough example, you'll have to use this as a basis for your exact implementation. There are cleaner solutions to this (and probably better regexes) but this will get you going.

Comment: @luca-jung suggestion of using XPATH would probably be the better option than the text manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know laravel (I use Symfony) and I am new to StackOverflow, but something like this could work:

```
if(strstr($result, 'name="twitter:image"')) {
  $namestart = strpos($result, 'name="twitter:image"');
  $substr1 = substr($result, $namestart);
  $contentstart = strpos($result, 'content="') + 8;
  $substr2 = substr($result, $contentstart);
  $contentend = strpos($substr, '"');
  $content = substr($result, $contentstart, $contentend)
}
```

Not tested!

Comment: It does not matter whether you know anything about any framework, but the current code is really fragile. There's a reason that `DOMDocument` exists ;)